# Can't understand the arguments of this make clean command

Tags: command-line, make

```
make clean all > make.log 2>&1
```

What does the `2>&1` signify here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will direct both the stdout and stderr of the `make` command to be put into the file make.log - please see [the bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) for more information